# Do you know about any good photo / 3D references sites?

Tags: modeling, texturing, 3d-view, customization

Do you know about any good photo / 3D references sites?

I want to create a 3D human models but I need good references for it. Do you know about any free or paid site that you trust? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender), [Rererence Images for Modeling](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5322/where-are-some-places-to-get-reference-images-for-modeling)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to introduce you my 3D.sk (biggest photo reference database) site where we actually offer new 3DScans! Oh, and we also prepared several packs of free photo references, 3DScans and 50% discounts for all of our portals for 3D fans, don't miss!

Download here: https://christmas.3d.sk/

Best,
Adam

Comment: Used to be a member and I can vouch for 3d.sk being a create resource for human reference.